# Number of day Count in every week in every month year wise between 2 dates in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I need to get the date and day count values between **two dates**.

let's suppose, we want to get the records between **1 july to 5 August**.

the output should be like below Table image:

we already know that we have **5 weeks in july** month and **1 week in august** month for this date range :

let's start with first week to last week : 
[image]

Comment: Two things - can you please explain what the 6 and 7 are referring to, days of what? Secondly, your query is doing the exact same thing for columns 3 and 4 with the word `week` prepended to the third column, hence, the numbers in the 4th column will always be the same numbers as in the 3rd column

Comment: 6 and 7 are referring to the number of days in a week.
yes this query is doing same for column 3 and 4 currently as i don't know the solution for doing above output

Yrar    Month   Week    DayCount    BillableHour
2017    May     Week 1    6          1378,90
2017    May     Week 2    7           509,40

Comment: `Year    Month   Week    DayCount    BillableHour
2017    May     Week 1    6          1378,90
2017    May     Week 2    7           509,40`

Comment: Please copy and paste your code into the text of your question.   Your question will be useless to future readers if that link ever goes dead.

Comment: My data is too long so I can't put on wall Plese give the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Goutam Singh. I think daycount should now be 7, 2 using the monday as start of the week.

```
SELECT 
    [DYear],    
    [DMonth],   
    [Week], 
    DayCount=COUNT(DISTINCT DayCount),
    BillableHour=SUM(BillableHour)
FROM
(

    SELECT
        [DYear]=(YEAR(Workdate)) ,
        [DMonth]=(DATENAME(MONTH, Workdate)) , 
        DateNames=datename(dw, Workdate),
        [Week]='Week ' + CAST((DATEPART(wk,DATEADD(DAY, -1,Workdate)) - MAX(DATEPART(wk,DATEADD(DAY, -1,Workdate)) )over(partition by (select null))+2) AS varchar(20)), 
        DayCount= (  WorkDate),
        BillableHour=(Convert(DECIMAL(16,2),[Hours]))
    FROM
        @TempTable

    WHERE
        Workdate between CONVERT(datetime,@FromDate) and CONVERT(datetime,@ToDate)
)G
GROUP BY
    [DYear],    
    [DMonth],   
    [Week]
```

Comment: The week starts from Monday, But I Your query start from Sunday.

Comment: Can you please include Sunday and week start from Monday. Thanks @MEdwin

Comment: I have modified the query. Have a look and say what you think.

Comment: Now fine but if I am adding more data for the wok date then dayCount is wrong.
@MEdwin can you get number of day between two dates 

I.E  
`declare @FromDate datetime = '2018-05-01'
declare @ToDate datetime = '2018-06-30'`

Year| MOnth| weekDay| NumberOfDay| WeekDaySatartDate | weekDayEndDate

Comment: hi Goutam Singh, see if you can explain a bit more. It is not very clear. you can save all data as csv file.

Comment: hi @MEdwin: thanks for your comment. I have edited my question for more understanding and clarification. please have a look to my question and share your comment if you need to ask anything.

Answer (score 0):

Number of days in a week column is not clear to me. otherwise, below will be the query. Just replace value and date columns with your appropriate column names.
select count(value),month(date),datepart(WEEKDAY,date()) as number of week,date
from t
group by date

Comment: Number of in a week means in 1st week how many days in 1st week if week start from 2018-05-01 to to and 2018-06-06 then number of day in week :- 6 thanks

Answer (score 0):

@Goutam Singh I have here an updated version. Basically, you need a CTE to build a template table for your query and then do a join depending on what is in the table you want to get the TotalHours. Let me know if that is what you want.

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATE='20180101'
DECLARE @EndDate DATE='20180901'

DECLARE @Dates TABLE(
      Workdate DATE  Primary Key
)

 DECLARE @TempTable TABLE (Id INT, Hours real, WorkDate DATETIME )
 INSERT INTO @TempTable
 SELECT 1,   5,   '03.05.2018 00:00:00'  UNION ALL 
 SELECT 2,   1.5,   '08.05.2018 00:00:00'  UNION ALL 
 SELECT 3,   3,   '01.05.2018 00:00:00'  UNION ALL 
 SELECT 4,   0,   '04.05.2018 00:00:00'  UNION ALL 
 SELECT 5,   2,   '03.05.2018 00:00:00'  UNION ALL 
 SELECT 6,   4,   '03.05.2018 00:00:00'  UNION ALL 
 SELECT 7,   2,   '05.05.2018 00:00:00'  UNION ALL 
 SELECT 8,   0.5,   '08.05.2018 00:00:00'  UNION ALL 
 SELECT 9,   0,   '01.05.2018 00:00:00'  UNION ALL 
 SELECT 10,   6,   '08.05.2018 00:00:00'  UNION ALL 
 SELECT 11,   8,   '02.05.2018 00:00:00'  UNION ALL 
 SELECT 12,   3.5,   '09.05.2018 00:00:00'  UNION ALL 
 SELECT 13,   1,   '09.05.2018 00:00:00'  UNION ALL 
 SELECT 14,   4,   '04.05.2018 00:00:00'  UNION ALL 
 SELECT 15,   1,   '03.05.2018 00:00:00'  UNION ALL 
 SELECT 16,   0,   '02.05.2018 00:00:00'  UNION ALL 
 SELECT 17,   3,   '05.05.2018 00:00:00'  UNION ALL 
 SELECT 18,   0.5,   '04.05.2018 00:00:00'  UNION ALL 
 SELECT 19,   2,   '09.05.2018 00:00:00'  UNION ALL 
 SELECT 20,   0,   '09.05.2018 00:00:00' 


 --DATEADD(DAY, -1,Workdate)
;WITH Dates AS(
      SELECT Workdate=@StartDate,WorkMonth=DATENAME(MONTH,@StartDate),WorkYear=YEAR(@StartDate), WorkWeek=datename(wk, DateAdd(DAY,-1,@StartDate)   )
      UNION ALL
      SELECT CurrDate=DateAdd(DAY,1,Workdate),WorkMonth=DATENAME(MONTH,DateAdd(DAY,1,Workdate)),YEAR(DateAdd(DAY,1,Workdate)),datename(wk, Workdate) FROM Dates D WHERE Workdate<@EndDate ---AND (DATENAME(MONTH,D.Workdate))=(DATENAME(MONTH,D.Workdate))
)


SELECT 
    WorkMonth,  
    NumWeek=ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY WorkMonth+cast(WorkYear as varchar(20)) ORDER BY WorkdateStart),
    NumDayWeek,
    WorkYear,   
    WorkdateStart, 
    WorkdateEnd,  
    TotalHours=SUM(TotalHours)
FROM
(


SELECT 
    D.Workdate, 
    D.WorkMonth,    
    D.WorkYear,
    D.WorkWeek, 
    WorkdateStart=MIN(D.Workdate) over(partition by cast(WorkWeek as varchar(20))+workmonth+cast(WorkYear as varchar(20))),
    WorkdateEnd=MAX(D.Workdate) over(partition by cast(WorkWeek as varchar(20))+workmonth+cast(WorkYear as varchar(20))),
    NumDayWeek=datediff(day,MIN(D.Workdate) over(partition by cast(D.WorkWeek as varchar(20))+workmonth+cast(WorkYear as varchar(20))),MAX(D.Workdate) over(partition by cast(D.WorkWeek as varchar(20))+workmonth+cast(WorkYear as varchar(20))))+1,
    T.TotalHours,
    T.DayCount
FROM
    Dates D
    LEFT JOIN
        (
         SELECT T.WorkDate, TotalHours=sum(T.Hours), DayCount=sum(case when T.Hours>0 then 1 else 0 end) FROM 
         @TempTable T
         GROUP BY
         T.WorkDate
        )T ON
         T.WorkDate = D.Workdate    

)Sub



GROUP BY

    WorkMonth,  
    WorkYear,
    WorkdateStart, 
    NumDayWeek,
    WorkdateEnd
ORDER BY
WorkdateStart  

option (maxrecursion 0)
```